# Django, как перейти на другую страницу

Tags: python, django

Только начал осваивать фреймфорк. По гайдам написал блог с добавлением постов с Админки.
Хотел дополнительно прикрутить в навигационную панель ссылку на страницу about.html

Пытался в views.py написать код

```
def about(request):
    template_name = 'about.html'
    return render(request, template_name)
```

Затем в urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),]
```

Однако не получается пойти по ссылке, вылазит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что что-то упускаю, но ничего толкового не нашел. Целевая страница не динамическая, ничего передавать на нее не нужно.

Может кто подсказать как исправить?

Comment: в urls.ry джанго поменял
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myblog.urls')),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]  а в urls приложения оставил urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),


]  Теперь на один порядок пишет меньше : 1.[name='home']
2.<slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что в urls.py есть патерн path('about/', views.about, name='about')
но нет его на картинке, который вы запостили. Перезапустите сервер
python manage.py runserver

И def about() у вас все строки на одном уровне.